# ImportError:cannot import name imaging from PIL

Tags: python, ubuntu

I successfully updated python alternatives from 3.7 to 3.8, then I installed pillow:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pil
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pil is already the newest version (6.1.0-1ubuntu0.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

Then:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I got these few errors. I was trying to open image to later check its size and format, therefore I wanted first import image submodule inside the pil module:

```
>>> import PIL.Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 95, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 95, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)
>>>
```

Can I please get some assistance on that?

Comment: Try first running this ```sudo apt-get install python-apt``` . And then your code

Comment: I do think Dhruv's suggesion may solve your `ModuleNotFoundError`. If you're stuck using the system Python for some reason, that may be your only option. Otherwise, see my answer below for my recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Python packages using OS-level tools is something you should avoid if at all possible. It targets the system-level Python, which means your Python code is at the mercy of any OS updates that change the language version or any of the installed packages. And it means that all your Python programming is dependent on the system Python, with no variations for specific projects.

Instead, use a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) aka "venv". You can create them right from the command line, using the standard library module `venv`. Here's a short demo:

```
$ python3 -m venv pildemo   
$ . pildemo/bin/activate
(pildemo) $ pip install pillow
Collecting pillow
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/b6/6979d88601932b0434854bcdd5cafeb239c4ed8a8c6c86c8363dd194f9a1/Pillow-7.1.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.1MB 537kB/s 
Installing collected packages: pillow
Successfully installed pillow-7.1.1

(pildemo) $ python
>>> import PIL.Image
>>> PIL.Image.__version__
'7.1.1'
```

The venv (named `pildemo` in my example) is a self-contained Python environment that will contain exactly the packages you want, and won't be affected by any changes to the system-level Python.